# How Do I Slow Down Sprite FPS in Pygame?

Tags: python, html, pygame

so I have my sprite here and I was wondering how to slow it down without slowing down my game?
[video of my sprite](https://gyazo.com/7f1057ae78e4450dd1fee99df47e872c) as you can see in the video its moving fast and I want to slow it down how could I do that

```
class snow:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.games = [
        pygame.image.load("key1.png"),
        pygame.image.load("key2.png"),
        pygame.image.load("key3.png"),
        pygame.image.load("key4.png"),
        pygame.image.load("key5.png"),
        pygame.image.load("key6.png"),
        pygame.image.load("key7.png")]
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.direction = "idk"
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "idk":
            window.blit(self.games[self.anim_index],self.rect)
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index == len(self.games):
                self.anim_index = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to slow down the animation, then you have to divide the animation index by a certain number. Add an attribute (`anim_frames`) which defines the number of frames for an image of the animation and divide `anim_index` by `anim_frames`. The quotient is the current image index. If it exceeds the maximum index, then restart the animation (`anim_index = 0`). Hence `anim_frames` contrls the speed of the animation. For instance:

```py
class snow:
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        # [...]

        self.anim_index = 0
        self.anim_frames = 10

        # [...]

    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        if self.direction == "idk":

            img_index = self.anim_index // self.anim_frames
            if img_index >= len(self.games):
                img_index = 0
                self.anim_index = 0
            self.anim_index += 1   

            window.blit(self.games[img_index], self.rect)
```